# How can I make a for loop starting a lot of processes?

Tags: scripting, process

I want to test some bug, and to do that I need to have a situation where the PID is larger than 99999. I am thinking of a bash script, a for loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Related: [What is the maximum value of a PID?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16883/80216)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this to start a process with the desired PID.

```
while true; do bash -c '[[ "$$" == 99999 ]] && echo PID is 99999'; done
```

You can wait until you get the desired PID and probably replace the `echo` statement to whatever you actually need to test.

**References**

[will the same pid be used after getting killed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128956/will-the-same-pid-be-used-after-getting-killed#comment206923_128959)

**EDIT**

Why the PID number grows? Is it due to the fact you run a different bash instance over and over again?

I believe what you have told is what's happening. This could be tested simply as below.

```
while true; do bash -c 'echo $$' ; done
```

We could see that the PID's keep getting incremented and from the man page of `bash`, I see that,

> -c string If the -c option is present, then commands are read from
>   string.  If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned
>                    to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

So as per my understanding, each `echo` statement in the above testing is getting executed as a separate process which is why we could see that the PID's are getting incremented.

Comment: Thanks very much. You have a minor mistake. Replace the double quotation marks in with single. Otherwise, the equality check operator doesn't work. (e.g. '$$' == 99999 )

Comment: @drpaneas, it worked with double quotes for me. Not sure if it needs to be replaced. Are you getting an error?

Comment: For me it doesn't work with double quotes. It treats the number as string (maybe). eg [["9999" == 9999 ]] returns false (in my shell).

Comment: Oh ok. Glad that the solution worked with single quotes for your test case. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, once again. Could you please explain, why the PID number grows? Is it due to the fact you run a different bash instance over and over again?

Comment: @drpaneas, That's a very good question. I believe whatever you have mentioned is what's happening and updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are trying to do there is most probably the better approach, but if you are determined something like

```
while [[ 1 == 1 ]]; do sleep 10000& done
```

will start many `sleeps`, but it may take a while to start all of them. When you will have enough processes just hit `Ctrl-C` to exit `while` loop.